# Update Flutter Code from old Bloc version to new

Tags: flutter, dart, migration, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm trying to update this code I have found from the old bloc package version to the newes version but i keep coming across this error.

'Bloc.on' ('void Function(FutureOr Function(E, Emitter), {Stream Function(Stream, Stream Function(E))? transformer})') isn't a valid concrete implementation of 'FilterBloc.on' ('void Function(dynamic Function(dynamic, dynamic))').dartinvalid_implementation_override'

Here the old code:

```
class FilterBloc extends Bloc<FilterEvent, FilterState> {
  FilterBloc() : super(FilterStateLoading());

  @override
  Stream<FilterState> mapEventToState(
    FilterEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is FilterLoad) {
      yield* _mapFilterLoadToState();
    }
    if (event is CategoryFilterUpdate) {
      yield* _mapCategoryFilterUpdatedToState(event, state);
    }
  }

  Stream<FilterState> _mapFilterLoadToState() async* {
    yield FilterStateLoaded(
        filter: Filter(
      categoryFilters: CategoryFilter.filters,
    ));
  }

  Stream<FilterState> _mapCategoryFilterUpdatedToState(
    CategoryFilterUpdate event,
    FilterState state,
  ) async* {
    if (state is FilterStateLoaded) {
      final List<CategoryFilter> updateCategoryFilters =
          state.filter.categoryFilters.map((categoryFilter) {
        return categoryFilter.id == event.categoryFilter.id
            ? event.categoryFilter
            : categoryFilter;
      }).toList();

      yield FilterStateLoaded(
          filter: Filter(
        categoryFilters: updateCategoryFilters,
      ));
    }
  }
}
```

My new Code:

```
class FilterBloc extends Bloc<FilterEvent, FilterState> {
  FilterBloc() : super(FilterStateLoading());

  on<FilterEvent>((event, emit) async {
    emit FilterStateLoaded(
      filter: Filter(
        categoryFilters: CategoryFilter.filters,
      ));
  });

  on<CategoryFilterUpdate>((event, emit) async {
    if (state is FilterStateLoaded) {
      final List<CategoryFilter> updateCategoryFilters =
          state.filter.categoryFilters.map((categoryFilter) {
        return categoryFilter.id == event.categoryFilter.id
            ? event.categoryFilter
            : categoryFilter;
      }).toList();

      yield FilterStateLoaded(
          filter: Filter(
        categoryFilters: updateCategoryFilters,
      ));
  }});
}
```

I look forward to getting tipps and learn new things from you.

Comment: Have you checked the dependency in your pubspec.yaml file? Make sure it's pointing to a version >= 8.0.0